# LINQ to SQL: filter nested objects with soft deletes

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, filtering, soft-delete

I'm using soft deleting in my database (`IsDeleted` field). I'm actively using `LoadWith` and `AssociateWith` methods to retrieve and filter nested records.

The thing is `AssociateWith` only works with properties that represents a one-to-many relationship.

```
DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
loadOption.LoadWith<User>(u = > u.Roles);
loadOption.AssociateWith<User>(u = > u.Roles.Where(r = > !r.IsDeleted));
```

In the example above I just say: *I want to retrieve users with related (undeleted) roles*.

But when I have one-to-one relationship, e.g. `Document` -> `File` (the only one file is related to the document) I'm unable to filter soft deleted object:

```
DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
loadOption.LoadWith<Document>(d = > d.File);
// the next certainly won't work
loadOption.AssociateWith<File>(f = > !f.IsDeleted);
```

So, is there any idea how to filter records within the one-to-one relationship?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I found only one suitable solution for this (apart from not to use soft deletes at all): to delete the soft-deletion relationship on entity update.

E.g. when I decided to remove a file from the document, I perform something like:

```
// this may be a part of update method
var file = document.File;
if (file.IsDeleted)
{
    // attach soft deleted file
    context.Files.Attach(file, true); 

    // remove a file reference
    document.File = null;
}

// attach document entity and submit changes
context.Documents.Attach(document, true);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

So, this may be a replacement for one-to-one relationship filtering on complex data retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
loadOptions.AssociateWith<File>(f => f.IsDeleted ? null : f);
```

this will give you null instead of files where IsDeleted is true.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. Gives the same error as `loadOption.AssociateWith<File>(f = > !f.IsDeleted)`: `Subquery is not supported on 'IsDeleted' of type 'Core.Entities.File'.`